# MacOS Sierra - brew installs graph-tool with openmp disabled

Tags: openmp, homebrew, graph-tool

Running `brew install graph-tool` on MacOs 10.13.4 does install `graph-tool` but `openmp` seems disabled.

Am I missing a `brew` option to have `openmp` enabled?

I did run `brew install libomp` prior to installing `graph-tool`.

```
Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 27 2018, 07:35:52) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import graph_tool as gt
>>> gt.openmp_enabled() 
False
>>>
```